# ListBox Winform question

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I use OpenFileDialog class, to open and display a filename chosen.

```
      List<string> paths;
    private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
         label1.Text = "Now you can save the file paths or remove them from the list above";
         paths.Add(openFileDialog1.FileName);
         listBox1.DataSource=paths ;//Only one file is displayed in the listbox
         Refresh();

    }
```

I want the user to choose several files and display all the files that he chose in the listbox that i have. The problem is that only one file path is displayed each time. What is funny, is that i thoguht that whenever i use pahts.Add,,new filename is added, but in reality it isnt so!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `Multiselect` in your file dialog to true and then use the `FileNames` property:

```
private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
   string[] files = openFileDialog1.FileNames;
   paths.AddRange(files);
   listBox1.DataSource=paths;
   Refresh();
}
```

Comment: +1 - a better option for multi-file-select for sure.  If the user wants to select multiple files from different locations, this needs to be combined with a means of building up the list as in the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Try `listBox1.DataSource = null;` and then setting it to `paths`.

Most likely the `ListBox` is not refreshing because the data source 'has not changed'.  *We* know that the content of the list has changed, however, from the `ListBox`'s standpoint, the object is the same.

Another better option is to use a `BindingList<string>` which *should* result in the `ListBox` updating whenever items are added without any additional fiddling.

Comment: files[i++] = openFileDialog1.FileName;
       
             listBox1.DataSource = files;// i simply did this and t did work. with one string it works..with a list of strings it doesnt :(

Comment: Have you tried setting `listBox1.DataSource = null;` prior to setting it equal to `files`?